# Cannot find output .a of Cocoa Static Library (in xcode 4)

Tags: objective-c, ios, static-libraries, ios-4.2, xcode4

I have a project with two targets, one is a Cocoa Static Library, the other is the accompanying test project.  Despite building the main project in different ways over and over again, **I cannot find the `.a` file** that I expect it to produce.

In fact, I cannot find the `build` folder associated with the project.  I need to link to the library in an app, but cannot do so if I can't find the file to link to.

- These properties are correctly set:

  ```
  (Build Products Path) SYMROOT = build
  (Intermediate Build Files Path) OBJROOT = $(SYMROOT)
  ```
- All tests pass (which means the code MUST be building right?)
- Breaking the code causes the build to break - again suggesting that it is building.

Also, the "Products > libproject.a" file is red in the xcode project navigation

I also checked the DerivedData directory, but all the seems to get created is the objects fot the OCunit stuff.  Still no `.a` file against which I can link.

**Where is my `.a` file?**

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` somewhere.